# How to make ImageButton directly open email composer on click?

Tags: android, email, imagebutton

I have made one application for epaper/emagazine in which I want to give an imagebutton for email composer that if I click on that button it will directly open the email composer inserting all the data of that page to the email composer message body asking only recipient address.

I have the output but instead of email it opens popup list asking messaging and bluetooth.

This is my code:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "lets.think.android@gmail.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Error Report");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "stacktrace");
activity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send error report..."));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `sendEmail()` method on button click:

```
final Context context = getApplicationContext();    
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openpdfbutton);          
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        sendEmail(context, new String[]{"abc@xyz.com"}, "Sending Email",
                  "Test Email", "I am body");
    }
});
```

Define the `sendEmail()` method:

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList,
            String title, String subject, String body) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");    
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);   
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));
}
```

And set permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: it is showing error on these words--recipientList,String body telling some syntax error

Comment: recipientList is the string array of recipients, String body is the data that you want to set the bosy of the page. Did you pass these valuea to the method?

Comment: i just copied wat u've given above and pasted to my code..its ok but i want this to work on button click..and those errors came because i pasted the whole code inside the button clicked function wich was already inside some class.....just tell me how to make it for button click

Comment: check my answer. i have edited line by line. It will work now

Comment: thanx for helping sunil bt i m getting error again in this line..     "sendEmail(context, new String[]{"abc@xyz.com....." under the context word telling "context cannot be resolved to a variable" and option is coming to change it to getBaseContext()

Comment: also i have not used xml to make buttons i have then in eclipse programatically in java in table layout

Comment: try with my answer now. I have passed that context variable also. I have edited. It will work for you.

Comment: huh...not again                                                   it is showing fatal error in logcat and force close option is showing..

Comment: 06-21 14:54:32.373: WARN/dalvikvm(459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-21 14:54:32.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 14:54:32.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(459): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
06-21 14:54:32.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(459):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:617)
and bla bla bla so on..i think i should start crying..or i'll hit my computer screen

Comment: i have sent u the whole coding on ur mail...please have a look...and help me....with regards..sunny..!!

Comment: i am in my office now. so i cannot access that mail.

Comment: Basically i am from orissa. now in bangalore

Comment: i m in delhi working with www.4cplus.com did my BE in computers from chennai and passout of this year...ok then after the office ours can u take a look to my project????

Comment: i will. can u send me the project?

Comment: ya i m sending u now..if possible please check the working for all the buttons means for imageswitcher,for facebook and also for email composer.......

Comment: @sunny @Sunil use the chat instead [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @BrunoLM thanks. I was not aware of that. I will use StackOverFlowchat. Thanks for your response

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo I want to know if the user have not already logined in Gmail then how it will work .I am new android

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

using intent we don't need permission..